# How do I limit a user to listening to only 3 songs before logging in?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I have the music player application in which I have 90 songs total.  I would like for the user to be able to listen to three of these without logging in, then require them to log in to listen to any others.

How would you suggest I implement this?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you rephrase?

Comment: Hi hariky007, Check your question for grammatical mistakes. If there are any, it would let the readers to mis interpret your question. Make your question clear.

Comment: Attempted translation:

I am building a music player with 90 songs.  If the user plays 3 songs, I want them to have to log in or (assuming he does not have an account) stop songs from playing.

Comment: Basically, each user can only listen to three songs before he/she has to login or else they won't be able to listen anymore. Or at least, that's what I took from it.

Comment: Be aware that if you are using a paid registration on your site to unlock these additional songs as a workaround for giving Apple its cut on in-app purchases or paying for the application, they will not respond well to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store how many songs the user has played in some sort of data structure that is persistent like CoreData.  Look into the apple tutorial on core data for ideas.  There are many examples with sample code.  If he listens to 3 songs then prompt him to the in app purchase for the upgraded version of your application.  The only way around this would be for the user to unistall and install the application.

That method is assuming you don't want to setup a server and log people's device id's

Edit: If you don't want to use core data then you can make sure your objects conform to the NSCoding protocol declared [Here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Protocols/NSCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: I don't want to use core data function or (in app purchase ) in my app

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just store the count in a NSUserDefaults key.